# How can I change the Navigation Bar without using `Application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, themes, uinavigationbar, appdelegate

I have been using the code below to change the navigation bar of ALL of my views:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

UIImage *gradientImage44 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"clear_navigation_bar_texture_44"]
                            resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage44 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

but I now want the navigation bar to be able to change to a different image that the user chooses based the 'theme' they want the app to be. Problem is, I can't put that code in here because it would only work when the app is loaded. So, I thought of making the code a seperate method and calling it in the didFinishLaunching... method and the viewController method that I call when the user changes the 'theme.' My question is then, how would I do this, or is there a better way of doing it?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to set the theme in the app delegate; you can do it anywhere you want (and you can even make it interactive). The only thing you need to be aware of is that attributes set via `UIAppearance` will only be instantiated with new views. If you have existing views that need updating, you need to do that manually. For example:

```
UIImage *gradientImage44 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"clear_navigation_bar_texture_44"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage44 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage44 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are they changing the theme in Settings.app? Just put your themeing code in `-applicationWillEnterForeground:` in your app delegate...

Comment: also, I believe this might break in widescreen mode, since nav bars are shorter there. Probably not noticeable.